# Where to get FW/BIOS for Sun Fire X4150

Tags: oracle, update, bios, sun, firmware

I have been trying to get the lastest software for the X4150. I get to this link http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/systems/patches/firmware/release-history-jsp-138416.html#X4150
but it gets me no where so.. just curious if anyone has 
ILOM 3.0.6.15.d r67788 
BIOS vers. 1ADQW068
?

Thanks

Comment: Firmware needs an Oracle support contract.

Answer (score 3):

You need access to My Oracle Support (MOS). Please contact to Oracle or Oracle partners for support.

Comment: So if you have the hardware, you can't get updates with out paying more for support you don't want? or do you get a access to MOS when you register your server with them or something?